# Are these different definitions of Likelihood functions In Machine Learning equivalent?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability

I have a lot of confusion in regards to the way likelihood functions are defined in the context of different machine learning algorithms.  For the context of this discussion, I will reference Andrew Ng 229 lecture notes.

*Here is my understanding thus far.*
In the context of classification, we have two different types of algorithms: discriminative and generative.  The goal in both of these cases is to determine the posterior probability, that is p(C_k|x;w), where w is parameter vector and x is feature vector and C_k is kth class.  The approaches are different as in discriminative we are trying to solve for the posterior probability directly given x.  And in the generative case, we are determining the conditional distributions p(x|C_k), and prior classes p(C_k), and using Bayes theorem to determine P(C_k|x;w).

From my understanding Bayes theorem takes the form:  p(parameters|data) = p(data|parameters)p(parameters)/p(data) where the likelihood function is p(data|parameters), posterior is p(parameters|data) and prior is p(parameters).
Now in the context of linear regression, we have the likelihood function:
p(y|X;w) where y is the vector of target values, X is design matrix.
This makes sense in according to how we defined the likelihood function above.

Now moving over to classification, the likelihood is defined still as p(y|X;w).  Will the likelihood always be defined as such ?
The posterior probability we want is p(y_i|x;w) for each class which is very weird since this is apparently the likelihood function as well.

When reading through a text, it just seems the likelihood is always defined to different ways, which just confuses me profusely.  Is there a difference in how the likelihood function should be interpreted for regression vs classification or say generative vs discriminative.  I.e the way the likelihood is defined in Gaussian discriminant analysis looks very different.

If anyone can recommend resources that go over this in detail I would appreciate this.

Comment: Migrate to http://stats.stackoverflow.com

Comment: When the output of an algorithm doesn't integrate to 1, as a posterior probability would, we call it likelihood. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is that the likelihood function is a function proportional to the probability of seeing the data conditional on all the parameters in your model. As you said in linear regression it is p(y|X,w) where w is your vector of regression coefficients and X is your design matrix.

In a classification context, your likelihood would be proportional to P(y|X,w) where y is your vector of **observed** class labels. You do not have a y_i for each class, because your training data was observed to be in one particular class. Given your model specification and your model parameters, for each observed data point you should be able to calculate the probability of seeing the observed class. This is your likelihood.

The posterior predictive distribution, p(y_new_i|X,y), is the probability you want in paragraph 4. This is distinct from the likelihood because it is the probability for some unobserved case, rather than the likelihood, which relates to your training data. Note that I removed w because typically you would want to marginalize over it rather than condition on it because there is still uncertainty in the estimate after training your model and you would want your predictions to marginalize over that rather than condition on one particular value.

As an aside, the goal of all classification methods is not to find a posterior distribution, only Bayesian methods are really concerned with a posterior and those methods are necessarily generative. There are plenty of non-Bayesian methods and plenty of non-probabilistic discriminative models out there.

Answer (score 0):

Any function proportional to `p(a|b)` where `a` is fixed is a likelihood function for `b`. Note that `p(a|b)` might be called something else, depending on what's interesting at the moment. For example, `p(a|b)` can also be called the posterior for `a` given `b`. The names don't really matter.